# Is it possible to show "No Records to Display" in EmptyDataTemplate Field in Gridview before binding it with the DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I want to display "No Records to Display" in the EmptyDataTemplate Field before binding the GridView with the DataSource.

After Binding the GridView with the Datasource, it displays the EmptyDataTemplate Field in the Gridview if the datasource returns null. But I want to show before binding it with the datasource. How this is possible?

Comment: why you need that, why dont you set empty dataset initially to achieve this

Comment: yes Ajay. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make new `DataTable` and assign that DataTable as DataSource before assigning orginal datasource

Answer (score 1):

not without binding it.

What you can do is simply bind it to an empty list of items (of the same type with the real items - new List() ) and later when you want to display the results, bind to the real data.